# The coordinate system bug between blender and three.js

Tags: json, three.js, blender, coordinate

In this three.js scene, I put my camera at (0, 0, 80) and put a directionalLight at ( 50, 50, 50 ).
Then, I create a white sphere geometry (the left sphere) and load a json model from blender (the right sphere).
However, the scene showed on the screen looks weird. The directional light project on the wrong surface of the json model.
It seems the problem of the coordinate system.
I try some tests today.
Here are the results.

- blender version:  v2.78a
- three.js version: r82
- exporter: io_three
- sphere type: UVsphere
- model filetype: .json

【io_three before version 76】

I got the correct result

[version 76](https://github.com/iceleaf97/blog/blob/gh-pages/three.js_json/io_three_r76.png)

[version 75](https://github.com/iceleaf97/blog/blob/gh-pages/three.js_json/io_three_r75.png)

【io_three "all versions" after 77 include 82】

I got the wrong result

[version 77](https://github.com/iceleaf97/blog/blob/gh-pages/three.js_json/io_three_r77.png)

[version 82](https://github.com/iceleaf97/blog/blob/gh-pages/three.js_json/io_three_r82.png)

Here is the [DEMO](https://iceleaf97.github.io/blog/three.js_json/demo.html) and [source code](https://github.com/iceleaf97/blog/tree/gh-pages/three.js_json).

Comment: Impossible to know, you have to share your source code and the JSON model or even better you can create a [gist](https://gist.github.com/).

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited my question again. It seems a bug of the exporter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has been solved.
[Github](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/10111)

changing a line in one of the blender -> threejs exporter files: in exporter/api/mesh.py change line 619 from:

vector = (vector[0], vector[2], -vector[1](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/10111))
to 
vector = (vector[0], vector[1](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/10111), vector[2])